# control for multi facet popup screen in android

Tags: android

I want to create a popup screen with multiple views, just like home screen but as a popup. As I am relatively new to android, so I am not aware if any such control is built in or do I need to use any library? or any hint would be helpful.

**EDIT**: I am looking for an alternation to viewpager, which is supported minimum on API8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the comment @codeMagic's comment below his answer, so posting here for the reference:

for `ViewPager` alternative we can use [ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) or [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) library, there minimum supported SDK are API level 1 & 4 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) may be what you're looking for. Added, in API 1, this let's you add a `View`(s) dynamically or you can set the `layout` to an already created xml file.

> A popup window that can be used to display an arbitrary view. The popup window is a floating container that appears on top of the current activity.

You also can create an `Activity` with whatever `Layout` you need in xml and give it a `Dialog` theme to make it look like a pop up by setting the

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in the `<activity>` tag of the `manifest`

Comment: actually main problem is a control that will have 3-4 views which are screen wide, and scrolled screen-by-screen

Comment: Oh, then you probably want [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: any alternative which is supported on API8 ?

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing that I am aware of that's available then. I haven't seen any similar libraries either

Comment: You might check out this [ViewFlow Library](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow). I've never used it but did some checking and this may give you what you want